# Javascript regexp problem

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a pattern like this in a javascript regexp:

```
"foo.bar".match(/foo\.(buz|bar)/)
```

but instead of returning foo.bar as I expect, it returns an array:

```
["foo.bar", "bar"]
```

I don't get it. How do I match foo.bar and foo.buz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correctly matching "foo.bar" or "foo.buz", but since you have a grouping (`(...)`), the returned array includes more than one item:

> [*Full Match*, *Match 1*, *Match 2*, ... , *Match N*]

According to [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), the result is **always an array**, and the **full matched text will be element 0**.  Elements 1...N will be the matches (in your case, "bar" or "buz").

If you want make sure your array is length 1, then you want to put `?:` after every `(` to make it a non-capturing group (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions, syntax `(?:x)`):

```
"foo.bar".match(/foo\.(?:buz|bar)/)
```

However, this is not necessary, as you can always just reference `result[0]` for the full match.

Incidentally, the `/g` option (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) again) will also get rid of the capturing groups from the result array.  Because `/g` executes a global search, the elements in the result array are used to display **all full matches** (and in your case given, there's just one).

Comment: but isn't the first match foo.bar? Or does it do the search from the right hand side?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure that I fully understand what's going on there, but at least I can get it to work. The term "non capturing group" has given me enough to do more research (since googling ?: doesn't work)

Comment: @stib - No problem!  Search SO for "capturing group" to learn all about the wonders of the parentheses in regular expressions :)

Answer (score 2):

Regex matching works in that way, that the first element of group is a whole string that is matched by whole regex. The same way if you will make a "big" group.

```
/(foo\.(buz|bar))/
```

The second and all next elements are those you matched by your own - so it is `buz` or `bar`:

```
(buz|bar)
```

In that case if you want not to batch just buz/bar you can exclude this group using `?:`

```
"foo.bar".match(/foo\.(?:buz|bar)/)
```

Your result will looks like:

```
["foo.bar"]
```

But it will still be an array with one element.